# Failing to set up SSH tunnel to private AWS API gateway API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, ssh-tunnel

I have a private AWS API Gateway REST API, meaning it's only accessible within my VPC.
I have a bastion SSH instance running in the VPC, meaning I can do stuff like this:

```
ssh -J ec2-user@<bastion> ec2-user@<ip of EC2 instance within my VPC>
```

From that instance I can then `curl` my API using the `https://<api-id>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/<my endpoint>` URL.

Now, for local testing, I'd like to tunnel this instance to a local port, so I try

```
ssh -J ec2-user@<bastion> -L 8888:<api-id>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443 ec2-user@<ip of EC2 instance within my VPC>
```

This command returns fine, but when I try to do `curl localhost:8888/dev/<my endpoint>`, I first get a certificate error, which is natural, but when I try using `curl -k localhost:8888/dev/<my endpoint>` to ignore the certificate, I simply get a 403 Forbidden response from AWS. There's nothing in my access logs for the REST API at all for these requests.

Is the 403 related to the fact that I'm ignoring the TLS certificate, or something else?
Is it possible at all to set up a tunnel like this?
Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to use plain HTTP for the API gateway REST API:s, otherwise I'd have preferred that for this type of thing.

Comment: Do you have any WAF associated with the API gateway?

Comment: @Nayeem No, there's no WAF!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

API Gateway requires the host header to match the API endpoint URL. Either add the hostname to your `/etc/hosts`

```
<api-id>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 127.0.0.1
```

and call it normally `curl https://<api-id>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:8888/dev/<my endpoint>`

or use curl's [`--resolve`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--resolve) flag

```
curl \
  --resolve <api-id>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443:localhost:8888 \
  localhost:8888/dev/<my endpoint>
```

Alternatively, if your bastion is configured to allow it, you can use `ssh` as a SOCKS5 proxy and proxy your request through the bastion.

In one shell session start the proxy

```
ssh -D 8888 ec2-user@<bastion>
```

and then in another shell, use it

```
export HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://localhost:8888
curl https://<api-id>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/<my endpoint>
```

Comment: This sounds very promising, thanks. I will try this after the holidays.

Comment: Late follow-up: The resolve flag did NOT work for me, however using /etc/hosts worked like a charm. This saved a lot of pain for me, thanks!
(As to why this question is getting downvotes, I'm not sure if people think it should've been posted on Serverfault instead - I don't really agree. This has everything to do with development in AWS.)

Comment: Faced exactly the same issue recently - `--resolve` flag worked for me with a tunnel open  through our bastion host on port 443 at both ends.  Then curl command: `curl https://[api-id].execute-api.[region].amazonaws.com/blah --resolve [api-id].execute-api.[region].amazonaws.com:443:127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Would have commented on the selected answer but I don't have enough reputation so here is what worked for me.

Port forward through jump server:

```
ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -f -N \
-L 127.0.0.1:<PORT>:<api-id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com:443 -p <PORT> <user>@<ip_address>
```

Add Host to curl with -k

```
curl -H "Host: <api-id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com" https://127.0.0.1:<PORT>/<my_endpoint> -k
```